# How to display other div when mouse is above diffrent div?

Tags: html, hover

i want to display .b div when cursor is hover on .a div. Is it possible to do?
I know that its possible to do when i put .b into .a div, but i would rather not to do it.

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title> 
        How to 
    </title>
    <style>
        .b{
            background-color: royalblue;
    display:none;
        }
        .a:hover > b{
            display: block;
        }
.a:hover{
    background-color: pink;
}
.a{
    background-color: lawngreen;
}

    </style>
</head> 
  
<body>
    <div class="a" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; "></div>
    <div class="b" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What about JS? It'll be probably more elegant and faster to solve it than use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could you use the css `+` plus selector

**Important notice:
This will only work if `a` is next to `b`, if there is (for example) a `c` between `a` and `c`, it will not work**

```html
<html> 
<head> 
    <title> 
        How to 
    </title>
    <style>
        .b{
            background-color: royalblue;
    display:none;
        }
        .a:hover + .b{
            display: block;
        }
.a:hover{
    background-color: pink;
}
.a{
    background-color: lawngreen;
}

    </style>
</head> 
  
<body>
    <div class="a" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; ">A</div>
    <div class="b" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">B</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.a{
    background-color: green;
}
.a:hover{
    background-color: pink;
}

.b{
    background-color: royalblue;
    display:none;
 }
 .a:hover + .b {
    display: block;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  
  <div class="a" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; "></div>
  <div class="b" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
    
</body>
```

Yes, you can do it by using [adjacent sibling selector (+)](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp#:%7E:text=Try%20it%20Yourself%20%C2%BB-,Adjacent%20Sibling%20Selector%20(%2B),-The%20adjacent%20sibling)

Here is a [demostration](https://codepen.io/GyanRoy/pen/NWXqEyj)

Only catch here is that style will be applied to the next element.

You can also check [General sibling selector(~)](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp#:%7E:text=Try%20it%20Yourself%20%C2%BB-,General%20Sibling%20Selector%20(%7E),-The%20general%20sibling)